# php+ register form not show on the remote server

Tags: php, mysql, remote-access

i am creating a register form in dreamweaver  this form appear in dreamweaver but when i try to send it  to the remote server the browser do not show all the register fields.

can anyone help me ???

until now the code is without a database

in the browser the register page show the first four fields

## register.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>RegisterPage</title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" /><style type="text/css">
.Required-field {
    background-color: #F00;
}
.required-fields {
    color: #FF0000;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
 <div id="banner">
  <div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="header">

    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="page-wrapper">
        <div id="page">
            <div id="wide-content">

                   <h2 class="registerTitle">Registration Fields</h2>
                   <h3 class="registerTitle">Sign Up Today....</h3>
                   <br /><br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
                   <!--registration fields-->
                   <form id="registerform" action="register.php" method="post">

    first name<span class="required-fields">*</span><br />
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Firstname" /><br /><br />
    last name<span class="required-fields">*</span><br />
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Lastname" />
    <br /> <br />
    Date of Birth<br />
    <input type="date" name="birthdate" value= "YYYY_MM_DD"  onfocus="if (this.value == 'YYYY_MM_DD') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'YYYY_MM_DD';}" /><br /><br />
        Specialization:<span class="required-fields">*</span><br />
        <select name="specialization"  class="select">
      <option value="0">-- Select Your Specialization --</option>

        <?php specializationQuery(); ?>
      </select>
        <br /> <br />
        <!--
        Governorate<span class="required-fields">*</span><br />
        <select id="governorate" name = 'governorate'>
                <?php echo $opt->ShowGovernorate(); ?>
                </select><br /><br />

      District<span class="required-fields">*</span><br />
      <select id="district" name="district">
                    <option value="0">choose...</option>
                </select><br /><br />
       Village<span class="required-fields">*</span><br />
       <select id="village" name="village">
                    <option value="0">choose...</option>
                </select>
        <br /> <br />
        -->         
       Email:<span class="required-fields">*</span><br />
       <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Adress" /><br /><br />         
       Username:<span class="required-fields">*</span><br />
       <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
       <br /><br />  
       Password:<span class="required-fields">*</span><br />
       <input type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="Password" /><br /><br />
       Re_Password:<span class="required-fields">*</span><br />
       <input type="password" name="pass2" placeholder="Validate Password" />
       <br /><br />       
    <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
     </form>
                   <!--end of registration fields-->


            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <div id="footer-bg">
    <div id="footer-content" class="container">
    <div id="column3">
            <h2>About Us</h2>
            <ul class="style1">
                <li class="first">Lam El Chamel is the first web development  system for me, this system had allow me to expand my knowledge and had put me in the first step of the programming career.

           Hope that this system will respnd for user's requirements, and as each system it will have a future enhancment with taking into consideration users feedback in the feedback section.
                </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <div id="column4">
            <h2>Navigation</h2>
            <ul class="style1">
                <li class="first"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer" class="container">
    <p>Copyright (c) 2013 Lam_El_Chamel.zxq.net All rights reserved. Design by Georges Matta.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note how your HTML is invalid (http://validator.w3.org/check). Might also cause some fields to not display on certain browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with this two functions

```
<?php specializationQuery(); ?>
```

and

```
 <?php echo $opt->ShowGovernorate(); ?>
```

try commenting them like this

```
 <?php //specializationQuery(); ?>
 <?php //echo $opt->ShowGovernorate(); ?>
```

and then use it it will show all fields.

Comment: thank you i was a mistake thank you it show all fields     sir i have a question this is my first time that i use the remote server how can i related this remote server to the database that i created in phpmyadmin?? (i work before on the localhost )

Comment: If you have same database and its table remote server as in local, you can easily work with mysql_connect function pointing to the remote server host and its database name.

Comment: you mean just i change the name of the host and the username and password and the database name ??

Comment: @AnotherTest that is true as per latest versions and trends. But not sure the User is aware of that looks like just a beginner in PHP so gave an overview.

Comment: @user2338686 that is true if your remote server allows remote connections you should be able to connect. Cheers :)

Comment: @chandresh_cool Trend or not, as of PHP 5.5.0 `mysql_*` is deprecated.

Comment: Correct that way let him first fix it will suggest it once he is able to fix it